# Plot 700 address marker into the google map using html php xml

Tags: php, javascript, html, xml, google-maps

I am plotting 700 address in google map using JavaScript and xml file.

So this JavaScript function is working fine till 300 address and it is plotting address correctly in map but afterwards it will slow down and hang the html page. So can we provide me better solution to achieve to plot all address in google map.

Here is xml sample file, having 675 address in that file & filename `xml1.xml`. E.g.

```
 <xml><listing>
    <storename>Borges Architectural Group</storename>
    <address>1478 Stone Point Dr # 350 Roseville CA 95661-2876 Placer</address>
    <person>OWNER Lane Borges</person>
    <phone>9167827200</phone>
    <web>www.borgesarch.com</web>
    <source>Infogroup</source>
    </listing>
    <listing>
    <storename>Carrier Johnson   Culture</storename>
    <address>1301 3rd Ave San Diego CA 92101-4012 San Diego</address>
    <person>PRESIDENT Michael C Johnson</person>
    <phone>6192392353</phone>
    <web>www.carrierjohnson.com</web>
    <source>Infogroup</source>
    </listing>
    </xml>
```

So I am reading this file in JavaScript for this I made one function for this to read xml content and add it to the array of address, so here I am getting total 675 address and I am passing one by one to the google map functions. So here is JavaScript for that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    var addresses=new Array(); 
    var info=new Array();
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(27.8333,-81.7170);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }
    var geo = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(); 

    function getAddress(search,info1, next) {
        geo.geocode({address:search}, function (results,status){            
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {             
              var p = results[0].geometry.location;
              var lat=p.lat();
              var lng=p.lng();            
              var msg = 'address="' + search + '" lat=' +lat+ ' lng=' +lng+ ' <br>'; 
              createMarker(search +"<br/>"+ info1,lat,lng);
            }          
            else{             
              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
                nextAddress--; 
              }else {
                var reason="Code "+status;
                var msg = 'address="' + search + '" error=' +reason+ ' <br>'; 
              }   
            }
            next();
          }
        );
      }

     function createMarker(add,lat,lng) {
       var contentString = add;
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
         map: map,
         zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
       });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
         infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
         infowindow.open(map,marker);
       });
       bounds.extend(marker.position);
     }

    function callajax(){
        downloadUrl('xml1.xml',function (listings_data){
        listings_data = xmlParse(listings_data);
        var markers = listings_data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('listing');       
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++)
        {
           var web;
           var storename= markers[i].getElementsByTagName('storename')[0].firstChild.data;
           addresses[i]= storename + " <br />" + markers[i].getElementsByTagName('address')[0].firstChild.data;
           var perosn= markers[i].getElementsByTagName('person')[0].firstChild.data;
           var phone= markers[i].getElementsByTagName('phone')[0].firstChild.data;
           var source=markers[i].getElementsByTagName('source')[0].firstChild.data;          
           if (typeof  markers[i].getElementsByTagName('web')[0] ==  "undefined")
                web='';
           else 
                web=markers[i].getElementsByTagName('web')[0].firstChild.data; 

           info[i]= perosn + " <br />"+ phone + " <br />"+ web +" <br />"+  source;
        }});
    }
    var nextAddress = 0;
    function theNext() {       
        if (nextAddress < addresses.length) {
          setTimeout('getAddress("'+addresses[nextAddress]+'","'+info[nextAddress]+'",theNext)',1  );
          nextAddress++;
        } else {  
          map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }
      } 

    function timeout_init() {
        setTimeout('theNext()', 3000);
    }

     callajax();
     timeout_init();
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't [geocode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#Geocoding) the addresses in the client.  That is a server intensive operation and is subject to a quota and rate limiting.

> If instead you wish to geocode static, known addresses, see the Geocoding web service documentation.

Geocode your addresses offline with the [web service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/index) (or something else) and use the resulting coordinates to display your map.